# openmp omp declare uniform this not supported in GCC?

Tags: c++, gcc, openmp, simd

I have a simple matrix class which I'd like to vectorize its add operator. However, uniform this seems not to be supported under GCC (works fine using Intel C++ Compiler). I am curios if there is any workaround. (below is the code along compile command)

Please let me know if you have any comments.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <cassert>
#include <omp.h>


#define printvar(a) std::cerr << (#a) << " = " << (a) << std::endl;
#define printline std::cerr << "FILE " << __FILE__ << " LINE " << __LINE__ << " FUNC: " << __func__ << std::endl;
#define NUMEL 10000

#pragma omp declare simd simdlen(2)
#pragma omp declare simd simdlen(4)
#pragma omp declare simd simdlen(8)
#pragma omp declare simd simdlen(16)
int myadd(int a, int b){
    return a+b;
}

template <typename V>
class Matrix {
public:
    V* data;
    int nrows, ncols;
    bool istemp = false;
    std::string name;
    Matrix(){
        data = NULL;
    }
    Matrix(int nrows, int ncols, V val, std::string name = "none"){

        this->nrows = nrows;
        this->ncols = ncols;
        this->name = name;


        data = (V*) malloc(sizeof(V)*nrows*ncols);
        for(int i = 0; i < numel(); i++){
            csi0(i) = val;
        }

    }

    Matrix(const Matrix& m){

        this->nrows = m.nrows;
        this->ncols = m.ncols;
        this->data = (V*) malloc(sizeof(V)*nrows*ncols);
        for(int i = 0; i < numel(); i++){
            csi0(i) = m.csi0(i);
        }

    }

    inline void swap(Matrix<V>& a, Matrix<V>& b){
        V* data = a.data; a.data = b.data; b.data = data; 
        int nrows = a.nrows; a.nrows = b.nrows; b.nrows = nrows; 
        int ncols = a.ncols; a.ncols = b.ncols; b.ncols = ncols; 
    }

    Matrix<V>& operator=(const Matrix<V>& m){
        Matrix<V> tmp(m);
        swap(*this,tmp);        
    }

    #pragma omp declare simd 
    #pragma omp declare simd simdlen(4) uniform(this)
    #pragma omp declare simd simdlen(8) uniform(this)
    #pragma omp declare simd simdlen(16) uniform(this)
    V& csi0 (int i) const {
        return this->data[i];
    }

    V& cij0 (int i, int j) const {
        return data[i+nrows*j];
    }

    int numel() const {     
        return nrows*ncols;
    }

    friend Matrix<V> operator+(const Matrix<V>& a, const Matrix<V>& b){

        assert(a.nrows == b.nrows && a.ncols == b.ncols);
        Matrix<V> retmat(a.nrows, a.ncols, 0, "retmat");
        #pragma omp parallel for simd 
        for(int i = 0; i < a.numel(); i++){
            retmat.csi0(i) = a.csi0(i) + b.csi0(i);
        }

        // retmat.istemp = true;
        return retmat;
    }

    ~Matrix(){
        if(data != NULL && !istemp){
    
            free(data);
        }

    }


    friend std::ostream& operator<<(std::ostream& os, Matrix<V> m){
        os << "{{" << std::endl;
        for(int i = 0; i < m.nrows; i++){
            for(int j = 0; j < m.ncols; j++){
                os << m.csi0(i) << ", ";
            }
            os << std::endl;
        }
        os << "}}" << std::endl;
        return os;
    }
};

int main(int argc, char const *argv[])
{
    Matrix<int> a(4,5,1), b(4,5,2), c;
    c = a + b;
    printvar(c)
}



int main_1(int argc, char const *argv[])
{
    int a[NUMEL], b[NUMEL], c[NUMEL];

    #pragma omp parallel for 
    for(int i = 0; i < NUMEL; i++){
        c[i] = myadd(a[i], b[i]);
    }
    return 0;
}
```

*Compile command*

```
g++.exe -fopt-info-all=all.optrpt -O3  -fopenmp -fopenmp-simd -mthreads -mavx -fmax-errors=5   -c gcc_ompsimd_test.cpp -Fo:gcc_ompsimd_test.o
gcc_ompsimd_test.cpp:65:46: error: expected unqualified-id before 'this'
  #pragma omp declare simd simdlen(4) uniform(this)
                                              ^~~~
gcc_ompsimd_test.cpp:66:46: error: expected unqualified-id before 'this'
  #pragma omp declare simd simdlen(8) uniform(this)
                                              ^~~~
gcc_ompsimd_test.cpp:67:47: error: expected unqualified-id before 'this'
  #pragma omp declare simd simdlen(16) uniform(this)
```

Comment: Why do you use `this->` at all? It makes no sense to me, as there is no local variable which is also named `data`. On the other hand, isn't it obvious to the compiler that `this` pointer is invariant across the SIMD lanes? Does `uniform(this)` makes any difference at all?

Comment: Generally gcc does support the `uniform` clause. It just doesn't work with the `this` pointer until gcc 6 (as can be found out by playing around a bit in [compiler explorer](https://godbolt.org/z/MxPMG3fY9)). As a workaround (other than just using a newer version of gcc) I would just use free functions instead of member functions. You could hide them in a `detail` or `impl` namespace.

Comment: @Laci The uniform clause declares one or more arguments to have an invariant value for all concurrent invocations of the function in the execution of a single SIMD loop. I tired uniform(this) with ICC too and it really changes the way the loops are optimized. If you check vectorization reports (ICC generating), you will notice, the uniform declarations are picked as a more suitable variant when vectorizing the function.

Comment: @Laci It is not obvious to the compilers, the purpose of the directives is to clarify that for the compiler. Compilers mostly take safe/conservative side.

Comment: @PaulG. I just couldn't find a table or sth clarify which openmp phrases are supported in what versions of GCC. Please let me know if any. BTW, I tried uniform(data) which leads to ` error: 'matrix<V>::data' is not an function argument #pragma omp declare simd uniform(data)`

Comment: @MikeITExpert There is [this](https://www.openmp.org/resources/openmp-compilers-tools/) part of the official website, but It doesn't contain such details. gcc supports all of OpenMP 4.5 from Version 6 on. As OpenMP 5 features are scattered through gcc versions >= 9, it is easiest to use e.g. the [Compiler Explorer](https://godbolt.org/) to find out what is supported on which version, I think.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It seems that in gcc you cannot use `uniform(this)` inside class declaration. It is OK in clang and Intel compilers. So, definition of the member function should not be in class declaration:

```
#pragma omp declare simd simdlen(16) uniform(this)
template <typename V>
V& Matrix<V>::csi0 (int i) const 
{
    return data[i];
}
```

Starting from OpenMP 4.5 the specification contains the following line ([2.8.2](https://www.openmp.org/wp-content/uploads/openmp-4.5.pdf)).

> The special *this* pointer can be used as if it was one of the arguments
> to the function in any of the **linear**, **aligned**, or **uniform** clauses.

So any OpenMP 4.5 compilant compiler should support it.

Comment: It works for GCC (i686-posix-dwarf-rev0, Built by MinGW-W64 project) 7.3.0, though I am not sure if that actually improves performance (I just don't understand GCC optimization report well enough let me know if there is any way to confirm its usefulness in the optimization reports.)

Comment: If performance is an issue it is better to use the Intel's compiler or MSYS2 (it has gcc 10.3 and clang11) to build windows binaries and Canonical Group's Ubuntu20.04 LTS (to build and run linux binaries on windows, which works surprisingly well)

Comment: Your answer is formulated as if it never works with gcc (especially together with the title of the question). I mean as gcc >= 6 fully supports OpenMP 4.5 it is implicit, but I think it should be more obvious in the answer that this is only a problem with gcc < 6.

Comment: @Paul, The OP's code gives the "<source>:65:49: error: expected unqualified-id before 'this'" error using **all the gcc versions** in compiler explorer. Did you manage to compile it without changing the source code in gcc?

Comment: Oh, sorry, I thought my minimal example (see godbolt link in my first comment) would be enough...

Comment: I took another look, and the significant difference is that my return type wasn't a reference. Should this maybe reported as a bug to gcc?

Comment: That's a good idea, go ahead. Fortunately, it is not a serious bug.